# Mongoose hangs on find() query

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose, keystonejs

I'm developing the backend for a website. The main app uses KeystoneJS to provide an admin UI for those who create content, and Keystone runs on top of MongoDB (specifically mongoose). The content is served to a main website and mobile app, and so to provide a backend API server to these I am writing a separate Express app.

The backend server attempts to access the underlying Mongo database using mongoose. I call `mongoose.connect()` using the following connection string and options:

```
var db_connection = 'mongodb://db_user:db_pass@localhost:27017/db';
var db_options = { 
    autoReconnect: false, 
    bufferMaxEntries: 0,
    poolSize: 10,
};
```

The connection is successfully opened, as logged by `mongoose.connection.on('connected', ...);` and I can manually look at the database using the MongoDB shell to confirm that there are documents in the database.

However, when I attempt to query the database, using:

```
var events = Event.find();
events.exec((err, events) => {
    console.log('/api/events: events found, sending to client');
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.json(events);
}).catch(err => console.log('error: ' + err));
```

where `Event` is `keystone.list('Event').model`, the query hangs and the `exec` callback never gets called, since the console log is never printed to the terminal.

I've properly initialized Keystone and imported the models, so I don't believe the issue is with the Keystone model but with mongoose itself. Additionally, if I execute the above code inside the Keystone app, it runs successfully, just not in my backend Express app.

Comment: which version of mongoose are you using ?

Comment: mongoose v5.0.1

Comment: if you write `console.log("test")` between your `events.find();` and `events.exec` lines, does it run?

Comment: @MohammadAli it does print "test"